# Audio defaults to HDMI except in OMXPlayer

Tags: pi-2, audio, raspbian-jessie

I'm about to throw in the towel on this one: On my RPi2B (Jessie) I am using HDMI out (HDMI->DVI cable to monitor) but want to use Headphone out for Audio. I've done the typical trouble shooting steps of using `raspi-config` to force audio via Headphone out, and tried changing the audio config files to force audio as well, but so far only OMXPlayer uses the Headphone port; any other audio (such as in Scratch or in Audacity) goes via HDMI. `alsamixer` keeps showing HDMI as default device as well.

I'm looking for any tips on what I can still look at to force ALSA and/or PulseAudio to use the headphone out. I assume the conflict is somewhere between these two audio layers. Who can help me out?